# How to order my table (SQL and JS)

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have a table that get her data form SQL query. I limited it on 3 rows by page.
Now, I have something like this:

```
Column 1

row 1
row 2
row 3

-> (for change page)
```

If I change page, this is what I see:

```
Column 1

row 4
row 5
row 6

<- ->
```

Now, the query is ordered by descending, but I need to order by ascending.

If I order it by ascending, the first page that it shows is the oldest row in DB, but I need to show the latest.
How can I do that?

Comment: please provide good information . this is quite confusing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL the ascending order is the default; maybe you want to order by descending.

You can do this with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY field_name DESC
```